# Please markdown process blog post links from the stack exchange blogs

Tags: feature-request

The code that processes site links is skipping the ask different blog to grab a title in a similar manner to how site questions get rendered from the raw links

See:

- [Where can I discuss Apple's Beta Seed program?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132382/where-can-i-discuss-apples-beta-seed-program)
- http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2015/08/beta-ios-9-and-el-capitan-questions-allowed/

  It would be nice if the blog posts were prettied up auto magically.

Comment: I'm confused—are you talking about oneboxes in chat per the title or just the Markdown parser obtaining the title for an internal link?

Comment: @grgarside Better?